# ffmpeg Audiosegment error in get audio chunks in socketIo server in python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, socket.io, blob, audiosegment

I want to send each audio chunk every minute.
this is the test code and i want to save audiofile and audio chunk file.
then, i will combine two audio files stop button was worked correctly but with set time function is not worked in python server.
there is python server code  with socketio

```
def handle_voice(sid,data): # blob 으로 들어온 데이터 
    # BytesIO를 사용하여 메모리 상에서 오디오 데이터를 로드
    audio_segment = AudioSegment.from_file(BytesIO(data), format="webm")
    directory = "dddd"
    # 오디오 파일로 저장
    #directory = str(names_sid.get(sid))
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)
 
    # 오디오 파일로 저장
    file_path = os.path.join(directory, f'{sid}.wav')
    audio_segment.export(file_path, format='wav') 
    print('오디오 파일 저장 완료')`
```

and there is client

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>마이크 테스트</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.5.2/socket.io.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type=checkbox id="chk-hear-mic"><label for="chk-hear-mic">마이크 소리 듣기</label>
    <button id="record">녹음</button>
    <button id="stop">정지</button>
    <div id="sound-clips"></div>
    <script>
        var socket = io('http://127.0.0.1:5000');
        const record = document.getElementById("record")
        const stop = document.getElementById("stop")
        const soundClips = document.getElementById("sound-clips")
        const chkHearMic = document.getElementById("chk-hear-mic")

        const audioCtx = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)() // 오디오 컨텍스트 정의

        const analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser()
        //        const distortion = audioCtx.createWaveShaper()
        //        const gainNode = audioCtx.createGain()
        //        const biquadFilter = audioCtx.createBiquadFilter()

        function makeSound(stream) {
            const source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream)
            socket.connect()
            source.connect(analyser)
            //            analyser.connect(distortion)
            //            distortion.connect(biquadFilter)
            //            biquadFilter.connect(gainNode)
            //            gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination) // connecting the different audio graph nodes together
            analyser.connect(audioCtx.destination)

        }

        if (navigator.mediaDevices) {
            console.log('getUserMedia supported.')

            const constraints = {
                audio: true
            }
            let chunks = []

            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
                .then(stream => {

                    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream)
                    
                    chkHearMic.onchange = e => {
                        if(e.target.checked == true) {
                            audioCtx.resume()
                            makeSound(stream)
                        } else {
                            audioCtx.suspend()
                        }
                    }
                    
                    record.onclick = () => {
                        mediaRecorder.start(1000)
                        console.log(mediaRecorder.state)
                        console.log("recorder started")
                        record.style.background = "red"
                        record.style.color = "black"
                    }

                    stop.onclick = () => {
                        mediaRecorder.stop()
                        console.log(mediaRecorder.state)
                        console.log("recorder stopped")
                        record.style.background = ""
                        record.style.color = ""
                    }

                    mediaRecorder.onstop = e => {
                        console.log("data available after MediaRecorder.stop() called.")
                        const bb = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/wav' })
                        socket.emit('voice',bb)
                        const clipName = prompt("오디오 파일 제목을 입력하세요.", new Date())

                        const clipContainer = document.createElement('article')
                        const clipLabel = document.createElement('p')
                        const audio = document.createElement('audio')
                        const deleteButton = document.createElement('button')

                        clipContainer.classList.add('clip')
                        audio.setAttribute('controls', '')
                        deleteButton.innerHTML = "삭제"
                        clipLabel.innerHTML = clipName

                        clipContainer.appendChild(audio)
                        clipContainer.appendChild(clipLabel)
                        clipContainer.appendChild(deleteButton)
                        soundClips.appendChild(clipContainer)

                        audio.controls = true
                        const blob = new Blob(chunks, {
                            'type': 'audio/ogg codecs=opus'
                        })

                        chunks = []
                        const audioURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
                        audio.src = audioURL
                        console.log("recorder stopped")

                        deleteButton.onclick = e => {
                            evtTgt = e.target
                            evtTgt  .parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(evtTgt.parentNode)
                        }
                    }

                  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
                    chunks.push(e.data)
                    if (chunks.length >= 5)
                    {
                        const bloddb = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/wav' })
                        socket.emit('voice', bloddb)
                         
                        chunks = []
                    }
                    mediaRecorder.sendData = function(buffer) {
                        const bloddb = new Blob(buffer, { 'type' : 'audio/wav' })
                        socket.emit('voice', bloddb)
}
};
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log('The following error occurred: ' + err)
                })
        }
    </script>
</body></html>
```

```
ask exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-54' coro=<InstrumentedAsyncServer._handle_event_internal() done, defined at f:\fastapi-socketio-wb38\.vent\Lib\site-packages\socketio\async_admin.py:274> exception=CouldntDecodeError('Decoding failed. ffmpeg returned error code: 3199971767\n\nOutput from ffmpeg/avlib:\n\nffmpeg version 6.1.1-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers\r\n  built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)\r\n  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --pkg-config=pkgconf --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libaribcaption --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-d3d11va --enable-libvpl --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint\r\n  libavutil      58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100\r\n  libavcodec     60. 31.102 / 60. 31.102\r\n  libavformat    60. 16.100 / 60. 16.100\r\n  libavdevice    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100\r\n  libavfilter     9. 12.100 /  9. 12.100\r\n  libswscale      7.  5.100 /  7.  5.100\r\n  libswresample   4. 12.100 /  4. 12.100\r\n  libpostproc    57.  3.100 / 57.  3.100\r\n[cache @ 000001d9828efe40] Inner protocol failed to seekback end : -40\r\n[matroska,webm @ 000001d9828efa00] EBML header parsing failed\r\n[cache @ 000001d9828efe40] Statistics, cache hits:0 cache misses:3\r\n[in#0 @ 000001d9828da3c0] Error opening input: Invalid data found when processing input\r\nError opening input file cache:pipe:0.\r\nError opening input files: Invalid data found when processing input\r\n')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\fastapi-socketio-wb38\.vent\Lib\site-packages\socketio\async_admin.py", line 276, in _handle_event_internal
    ret = await self.sio.__handle_event_internal(server, sid, eio_sid,
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "f:\fastapi-socketio-wb38\.vent\Lib\site-packages\socketio\async_server.py", line 597, in _handle_event_internal
    r = await server._trigger_event(data[0], namespace, sid, *data[1:])
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "f:\fastapi-socketio-wb38\.vent\Lib\site-packages\socketio\async_server.py", line 635, in _trigger_event
    ret = handler(*args)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "f:\fastapi-socketio-wb38\Python-Javascript-Websocket-Video-Streaming--main\poom2.py", line 153, in handle_voice
    audio_segment = AudioSegment.from_file(BytesIO(data), format="webm")
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "f:\fastapi-socketio-wb38\.vent\Lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 773, in from_file
    raise CouldntDecodeError(
pydub.exceptions.CouldntDecodeError: Decoding failed. ffmpeg returned error code: 3199971767

Output from ffmpeg/avlib:

ffmpeg version 6.1.1-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --pkg-config=pkgconf --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libaribcaption --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-d3d11va --enable-libvpl --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavcodec     60. 31.102 / 60. 31.102
  libavformat    60. 16.100 / 60. 16.100
  libavdevice    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavfilter     9. 12.100 /  9. 12.100
  libswscale      7.  5.100 /  7.  5.100
  libswresample   4. 12.100 /  4. 12.100
  libpostproc    57.  3.100 / 57.  3.100
[cache @ 000001d9828efe40] Inner protocol failed to seekback end : -40
[matroska,webm @ 000001d9828efa00] EBML header parsing failed
[cache @ 000001d9828efe40] Statistics, cache hits:0 cache misses:3
[in#0 @ 000001d9828da3c0] Error opening input: Invalid data found when processing input
Error opening input file cache:pipe:0.
Error opening input files: Invalid data found when processing input
```

im using version of ffmpeg-6.1.1-full_build.
i dont know this error exist the stop button sent event correctly. but chunk data was not work correctly in python server.
my english was so bad. sry